# How to remove value from dropdown box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am new with jQuery stuff so I need your support.

I am using [Bootstrap Select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) script and I want to remove `Price,` when user select to drop-down.

If user select values `Price,` will be removed else add `Price,`

My Sample [JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/Amk2YM)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `title` option like so: 
`$(".sort_low_to_high").selectpicker({title:'Price'});`

**Demo:** [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CF43E/)

Answer (score 1):

You are giving `multiple` attribute in `<select>` tag. This will make the selection as multiple, but sorting will either be high to low or low to high. So you should remove `multiple` attribute.
My Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pvT8Q/53/

Answer (score 0):

You have not given id's to  give id and in your code.

after that you can remove it by $("#id").remove();

Answer (score 0):

This will play nicely with the Bootstrap markup: http://jsfiddle.net/pvT8Q/54/

```
$('.bootstrap-select').on('click', function() {
    $('.selectpicker').find('li').first().hide();
});
```